# How to refresh the Auditing Log programmatically

Tags: 2010, auditing

I would like to know if there's a way to refresh the Auditing log programmatically, because we need it to see in real time which the last accessed document was within a Document Library.

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by update?  Change the data?

If you just need to view the data, some code like this has worked for me:

```
SPAuditQuery query = new SPAuditQuery(site);
query.AddEventRestriction(SPAuditEventType.View);
query.RestrictToList(list);
SPAuditEntryCollection auditCol = list.Audit.GetEntries(query);
```

Then you just loop through the auditCol and add it to a dataset and bind to a datagrid for output.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to make sure you are setup to audit the events you are looking to capture.  Here is a good overview blog post:  http://sharepointknowledgebase.blogspot.com/2010/09/sharepoint2010-site-collection-auditing.html